# Calling a controller on button click

Tags: angularjs

I need a small help.I have a controller in angular as

```
app.controller('dataTableCtrl', function($scope, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) 
{
  ...
}
```

How can i call this controler only after the button ng-click is done.can anyone please help me out in this.

**Note:**
I already have a main controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this whith the `ng-controller` direktive. From the [Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller).

Disclaimer: I do not know how to nest controllers.

In your case:

```
<div ng-controller="dataTableCtrl" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="yourFuncHere">
  Button label
</div>
```

**But!:** you should think about to externalise your data table logic into a factory and youst call this factory from your main ctrl. Normaly it is better style to just have on ctrl per page (navigationCtrl aside)